# how do I fix these warnings from sqlite in my in php application?

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, ubuntu, apache2

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/zip.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Try googling the error message.  The libraries need to be installed.

Comment: Check laravel server requirements and install necessary libraries

Comment: tnks @Markandeya, I can solved problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problems with one of the answers of the suggested post suggestions, simply the warnings disappeared after I installed the libraries that were missing, thanks!

then the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```